# Codeigniter: Referencing a specific array index returned in model result

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'm still trying to wrap my head around passing db query results from a model back to controller and finally to a view.  I seem to be getting the data to the right place, I'm just not sure how to best access the resulting array of objects in the view.

Specifically, I'm trying to query my db for the most recent 7 distinct dates that someone has submitted a link.  I get back an array of dates, and then for each of those dates I do a query for all links submitted on that date and store the results in an array.  Then in the view, for each of those distinct dates, I show a header (the date), immediately followed by the links associated with it.

The array that come from my distinct date query ($link_headers):

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-08-11)
    [1] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-05-03)
    [2] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-04-21)
    [3] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-04-10)
    [4] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-03-04)
    [5] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-02-28)
    [6] => stdClass Object([added_date] => 2011-02-22)

)
```

The array that comes from my query for actual links submitted ($links_result):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1178
                    [link_url] => http://www.amazon.com/Silicone-Rubber-CASSETTE-Design-IPHONE/dp/B004YDJWOY
                    [link_name] => Silicone Skin BLACK CASSETTE TAPE
                    [link_notes] => iPhone case... probably won't fit in my dock.
                    [added_date] => 2011-08-11
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 4
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1177
                    [link_url] => http://snorby.org/
                    [link_name] => Snorby - Snort front-end
                    [link_notes] => 
                    [added_date] => 2011-05-03
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 4
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1176
                    [link_url] => http://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/17/business/17excerpt.html?_r=4&pagewanted=1&ref=business
                    [link_name] => Corner Office - The 5 Habits of Highly Effective C.E.O.s
                    [link_notes] => Sounds a lot like what Nathanial said...
                    [added_date] => 2011-04-21
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 4
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1175
                    [link_url] => http://chezlarsson.com/myblog/2010/06/panduro-concrete-challenge-3.html
                    [link_name] => Concrete book-ends
                    [link_notes] => Cool look... 
                    [added_date] => 2011-04-10
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 4
                    [public] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1174
                    [link_url] => http://themeforest.net/item/reciprocity-photo-blog-gallery/154590
                    [link_name] => Site Templates - Reciprocity - Photo Blog
                    [link_notes] => 
                    [added_date] => 2011-04-10
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 5
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1173
                    [link_url] => http://lifehacker.com/#!5771943/the-always-up+to+date-guide-to-jailbreaking-your-ios-device
                    [link_name] => The Always Up-to-Date Guide to Jailbreaking Your iOS Device
                    [link_notes] => 
                    [added_date] => 2011-03-04
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 4
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1172
                    [link_url] => http://lifehacker.com/#!5754463/how-to-jailbreak-your-ios-421-device
                    [link_name] => How to Jailbreak Your iOS 4.2.1 Device
                    [link_notes] => 
                    [added_date] => 2011-02-28
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 4
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [link_id] => 1171
                    [link_url] => http://www.bitplumber.net/2010/10/a-cassandra-hardware-stack-dell-c1100s-ocz-vertex-2-ssds-with-sandforce-arista-7048s/
                    [link_name] => A Cassandra Hardware Stack
                    [link_notes] => 
                    [added_date] => 2011-02-22
                    [flag_new] => 1
                    [rating] => 3
                    [public] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

... all seems fine enough.  But my problem comes from my view, where I'm trying to build the HTML as described above.  A simplified view of the code I'm trying to get to work is as follows:

```
foreach ($link_headers as $header) {

echo "INDEX: ". $links_headers .", ADDED DATE: ". $header->added_date ."<BR>";

    foreach ($links_result[$link_headers] as $result){
        echo $result->added_date ."<BR>";
        echo $result->link_name ."<BR><BR>";
    }
}
```

So, I'm trying to use the index of the first one to tell my foreach loop which index of the second array to loop through and get the content.  Clearly I'm misusing the $links_result[$link_headers] variable(s) but I left it in to show what I was trying to do.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I dont use CodeIgniter but whether within th framework or from PHP i would just grab it all in one go and then the issue with the indexes becomes moot:

```
SELECT * FROM model_table mt WHERE mt.added_date IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT md.added_date from model_table md
   ORDER BY md.added_date DESC
   LIMIT 7
) ORDER BY mt.added_date DESC
```

That should get you an array of models ordered by date limted to the 7 most recent dates. So then its just a matter of choosing when to display a header:

```
$current = null;
foreach($links as $link) {
   if($link->added_date !== $current) {
      // show the header and set current to the current date
      $current = $link->added_date;
      echo 'HEADER: Added on ' . $current . '<br />';
   }

   echo $row->added_date ."<BR>";
   echo $row->link_name ."<BR><BR>";
}
```